# Error: Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, teamcity

I am trying to run a clean build of an android project using gradlew on TeamCity. It runs a lot of tasks but then returns this error:

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
```

Then it fails. What is the cause of this issue and how can I fix it?

Comment: This is a warning. The error is something else.

Comment: @laalto I get "Execution failed for task ':app:compileProdDebugKotlin'." in my TeamCity log and then a huge list of exceptions like this "* Exception is:
[09:21:53][Gradle failure report] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileProdDebugKotlin'.
[09:21:53][Gradle failure report]  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)"